# Vim autocommand creates weird file

Tags: vim, settings, vimrc

I've just set up slackware 14 on a virtualbox. As one does, I immediatly created/altered my `.bashrc` and, more importantly, my `.vimrc` files.

To avoid writing huge lines of code, I usually add something like

```
au BufWinEnter * w:m1=matchadd('ErrorMsg','\%>100v.\+', -1)
if version >= 702
    au BufWinLeave * call clearmatches()
endif
```

I've used these settings for quite a while now, only this time, whenever I open a file in vim, a weird file is being created, with `:m1=matchadd('ErrorMsg','\%>100v.\+', -1)` as its name.
I've reduced my `.vimrc` file to just the basics, which I believe can't have anything to do with this oddity (vim-7.3.645-x86_64-1):

```
set nocompatible
set ai
set nu
set ruler
set hlsearch
set hidden
set showcmd
set cursorline
set confirm
syntax on
color evening
au BufWinEnter * w:m1=matchadd('ErrorMsg','\%>100v.\+', -1)
if version >= 702
    au BufWinLeave * call clearmatches()
endif
```

Any ideas what is causing this behaviour, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected; the autocmd executes the *Ex command* `w:m1=matchadd('ErrorMsg','\%>100v.\+', -1)`. `w` is the short form of `write`, what follows is interpreted as the file name.

I guess a `:let` went missing, because then the command makes sense: `let w:m1=...` defines a window-local variable `m1` and assigns the result of the `matchadd()` call to it.

---

The autocmd appears to highlight all characters beyond column 100. Note that in recent Vim 7.3 versions, you can use the `'colorcolumn'` feature for that:

```
:set colorcolumn=101
```

Comment: Thanks, I did indeed miss the `let`... probably `d+w` somewhere by accident. Anyway, I will be using `colorcolumn` from now on.

Answer (score 0):

If you add,

set vbs=1 " Verbose error reporting Zero = Norm to Nine = Max

into your .vimrc and start with a 3 or 4 it will show you all the files loaded/called (and a lot more as you push to 9) as you are opening vim/files.

Not an exact answer, but could help you track it down.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I already tried that. That just informs me that `:m1=matchadd.... [NEW]` was written to $PWD. Thanks for the input, though. Ingo Karkat's answer was correct. I can't believe I missed the `let`... And I will be changing the regex autocommand to `colorcolumn` from now on :)

Comment: Yep, I see the other reply now, teach me to take 10~15 to finish my reply, I expected it was given as I was typing and reading another screen.
Glad you have an answer.